# Xamarin: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Google.Apis.Core'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I recently installed some of Google's .NET API Client Libraries on my Xamarin project (a Shared Project, to be specific) in order to fetch links for YouTube results related to a search query. To be exact, the three NuGet packages that I installed were:

- `Google.Apis`, `v1.34.0`
- `Google.Apis.Core`, `v1.34.0`
- `Google.Apis.YouTube.v3`, `v1.34.0.1226`

My application is intended to be cross-platform, so I ensured that each package was installed on both the Android and iOS projects. The code compiled fine, and the imports that I made to classes in each of the packages compiled fine as well. When I start the compiler, however, I receive this error:

```
Failed to load assembly from stream: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.34.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'
```

Then, when I check the NuGet window for the entire solution to see if the package is installed for both projects, both the boxes untick themselves for each of the three packages (even though the `.csproj` files both contain statements including each package). I'm not sure if this is due to incompatibility because other incompatible packages I've seen simply fail to install. I've tried cleaning the solution and even adding the packages individually; when adding them individually, the window displays that they're installed for each package but then throws the same error the next time I build.

**Some information concerning the problem:**

- Building on Debug
- Building on AnyCpu
- Building on Live Player with a Samsung Galaxy running Android 8.0, API 26.

The full error log is listed here for convenience.

```
Failed to load assembly from stream: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.34.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'
at Upsight.LoadedAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference name) [0x001e0] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00038] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00014] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve () [0x00006] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference self) [0x00000] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeEnum (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference enum_type) [0x00000] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElementValue (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x0002f] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElement (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00015] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeFixedArgument (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00015] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeConstructorArguments (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute attribute, Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1[T] parameters) [0x0002e] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader.ReadCustomAttributeSignature (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute attribute) [0x0003c] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.<Resolve>b__35_0 (Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute attribute, Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader reader) [0x00000] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet] (TItem item, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] read) [0x00029] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.Resolve () [0x00017] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.CustomAttribute.get_ConstructorArguments () [0x00000] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadCustomAttributes (Mono.Cecil.ICustomAttributeProvider provider) [0x00024] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadProperties (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00031] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00068] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadTypes (Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1[T] types) [0x0000c] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadModule (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, System.Boolean resolve_attributes) [0x0004f] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.<ReadModule>b__2_0 (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader reader) [0x00007] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[TItem,TRet] (TItem item, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] read) [0x00029] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadModule () [0x00000] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule (Mono.Cecil.PE.Image image, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0007b] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (Mono.Disposable`1[T] stream, System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0000d] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00012] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <0ea22156f1264b96bf10daa7186c2c1f>:0 
at NInterpret.CecilLoader.loadStreamWithResolver (System.IO.Stream peStream, Mono.Cecil.IAssemblyResolver resolver) [0x0000f] in <5a7d38ec7eef0f2aa7450383ec387d5a>:0 
at <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LoadedAssemblies+TryLoadAsync@325-4.Invoke (System.Byte[] _arg2) [0x00008] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0 
at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncBuilderImpl+args@835-1[a,b].Invoke (a a) [0x00016] in <55b16819904cf4daa74503831968b155>:0
```

If there's any way I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve without using the Google API, that might be the best way to circumvent the entire problem. I've already implemented this on a WPF test of this concept, however, so if there's an easy-ish solution I'd be glad to know about it. I'll provide any additional information that is necessary, but please know I'm likely not much help concerning this as I'm getting to know how Xamarin works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google api .net client library does not support Xarmain authentication.

please see [issue 984](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/984)